# Need help to create a Pie chart in AngularJs using a dynamic JSON file data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

My requirement is that I have a json file which is fetched from a database using java. I would like to fetch a particular column from that json file and display that data using a pie chart(with the help of angularjs and fusion chart)so that the values in that data changes dynamically in the pie chart. I have attached the chart which I have used for trial. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CanvasJS pie Charts or

here is the Exapmle -> [HERE](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-pie-chart/)

Or you can Even Use High Charts

Exapmle Here -> [HERE](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown/dark-unica)

So you Just need to call you Json value According to Your Need is the Charts

Answer (score 0):

I have used Angular NVD3 and Angular Google charts for similar kind of requirement in which large dataset is used(approx 15000 records) in a SharePoint 2013 App. Both are easy and open source.